# How to fix "Add to Favorites" menu item when adding Konsole to Gnome 3 favorites

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, konsole

Normally in Gnome 3 to add an Application the Favorites, you can launch it, then right click the app icon in the doc and select "Add to Favorites".

But on Ubuntu 16.04 specifically for the "Konsole" application, the "Add to Favorites" option is missing from the context menu.

I can drag the Konsole application the application launching menu, but this creates a dock entry that only *launches* new Konsole windows, which generate a second menu entry. If it matters I'm using the "Dash to Dock" extension.

Thanks.